# Disable Android Home,Back and Recent navigation button in react-native app

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want to disable android navigation when I open my react-native app for Kiosk.
I don't want anyone to close the application by pressing any of the home back and recent buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onBackPressed` method and prevent closing the app, but you **can't override** the home button.

Therefore, the solution is to launch back the kiosk activity in `onPause()` method.
(use flag BROUGHT_TO_FRONT)

Comment: does it use backhandler?